# OpenVPN connects but block websites doesn't open on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, vpn, 17.04, openvpn

I use the OpenVPN connection for a long time to open the block websites. I have 2 computers. Desktop and laptop. I use Ubuntu 16.04 on desktop and 17.04 on laptop. Since I update desktop a few days ago the OpenVPN connection connects but doesn't work. Chrome says:

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

It means that block websites doesn't open anymore, but other websites open as usual. Same issue on laptop with a fresh Ubuntu 17.04 installed.

I have tested some DNS on OpenVPN connection but doesn't work and I read some articles from other users but didn't help.

Comment: I am from iran and many wesites are blocked just like china as you know. like twitter and facebook and google plus and many others. I use this connection on my android devices and works perfectly. please tell me what kind of information do you need.

Comment: as I said , this connection works on other divices like android and windows devices. I have this problem since I update my 16.04 ubuntu. 3 or 4 days ago.

Comment: no. just block websites. google.com is not blocked but plus.google.com is blocked. (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this looks like a DNS leak issue you can fix this

1. Edit The .ovpn File

You just need to add these three lines of config into your .ovpn file. Add these to the end of file as new lines.

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Explanation: OpenVPN (if you install it from Ubuntu repo) has a special script named update-resolv-conf. This script will update your /etc/resolv.conf file automatically. It will force OpenVPN to use default DNS from your .ovpn file.

2. Run The .ovpn File

sudo openvpn --config name_of_your_file.ovpn

3. Test DNS Leak

Browse http://dnsleaktest.com and start a standard test. See that your DNS changed into another than your ISP DNS (thus VPN's DNS). In this example, I use vpngate VPN service and Google as my DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't leave a comment to your question (due to lack of reputation points). However, I also hit this with my recent upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04. I'm not sure how I got it to work (which is why I'd rather leave a comment than use this answer form). I don't know if you're using openvpn via the command line (my situation) but if you are this worked for me:

1. `sudo systemctl stop NewtworkManager.service`
2. `sudo openvpn --config "your-config-file-here.ovpn" &`
3. Wait for: "Initialization Sequence Completed" from openvpn
4. Test that you can reach the outside world: `ping www.google.com` or use `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` to see that your IP address has changed.
5. `sudo pkill -TERM openvpn`
6. `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service`

After performing these steps, subsequent starts of openvpn worked normally without having to resort to stopping NetworkManager. I even rebooted the machine and tested again to verify that it survived a reboot.

I can only guess that NetworkManager was preventing openvpn from touching some system files. Either way I wouldn't consider this a fix, but rather a work-around that may/may not help you.

Comment: I use openvpn with network manager.
I run this command sudo systemctl stop NewtworkManager.service
) and the result is : Failed to stop NewtworkManager.service: Unit NewtworkManager.service not loaded.